# Generate all possible combinations of elements in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

I've been trying to create a script where every possible combination of a list will be printed **[where (1,2) and (2,1) will be counted as different entry]**.
For example:

```
c = [1,2]
# do something magical
print(c with magical stuff) 
>>>[(1), (2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I've tried itertools.permutations. It shows output as >>> () (1,) (2,) (1, 2) (2, 1). However, it doesn't include (1, 1) and (2,2)

Any help will be hugely appreciated. I'm new to coding (I'm very fluent in printing "Hello World!" though :3)

Comment: But the output you showed _does_ both include `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Try `itertools.product`:

```
def foo(l):
    yield from itertools.product(l)
    yield from itertools.product(l, l)
```

---

```
for x in foo([1, 2]):
     print(x)

(1,)
(2,)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

Note that the `yield from` syntax is available from python3.3 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
c = [1,2]
for i in itertools.permutations(c):
     print i
```

yields

```
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It does. However, it does not combine all the elements like (1, 1) and (2, 2). Sorry for the confusing title.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some built-in (or more likely numpy) packages that can do this for you, but it is an excellent exercises to do it yourself.

One question - are you interested exclusively in length-2 permutation, or do you want to write a function for arbitrarily long permutations?

Also, see: [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it shows however that he is worthy of the 50 rep required for *commenting*. That is the reason I upvoted anyway. But Coldspeed is right Mike. This would be more appropriate as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: wasnt sure if it was appropriate to code up a beginner's example, opted to give some high level thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Make combinations with replacement and then permute the results, keeping only unique results.

```
import itertools as it 


combs = it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations_with_replacement(c, i) for i in range(1,3))
perms = it.chain.from_iterable([set(it.permutations(i)) for i in combs])
list(perms)
# [(1,), (2,), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```